# Is it possible in Java to forbid certain superclasses in generics?

Tags: java, generics

I would like to ask if it is possible in Java 8+ to declare a generic bound `T` so that it extends superclass/superinterface `U` (which could be `Object`, or `Serializable`) but breaks *compilation* if `T` extends `L` (which must extend `U` first).

I have found this problem using filter range objects: one of my developers invoked the wrong method and spent much time questioning on why it was giving inconsistent results. So I wanted to help her changing the method signature, someway, to early detect that she is using wrong code.

I will display my example case in a very simplified way. We are talking about tables and dynamic filters.

```
#Displays a text "[field name] is equal to [value]"
#Value (T) must be Oject
#Internally uses Object::toString
#Null shows blank string
public static String <T> localizeEq(Localizable fieldName, T value);
       <LocalDate> localize(forI18nLabel("DATE_OF_BIRTH_LABEL",dateOfBirth)
       "Date of birth equals 01/01/1900" (en)
       "syntymäaika on 01/01/1990" (fi)

#Additional diplays for "ge, gte, le..."
#Overload methods not displayed

#SimpleFilter is {op:"ge|ge|eq...",value:""}}
#The effective display depends on the op attribute
#Example "[field name] is [operator] [value]"
#Example "[field name] is less or equal than [upper]"
#If <filter != null but filter.op == null || filter.value> the method returns null
public static String <T> localize(Localizable fieldName, SimpleFilter<T> filter)
   #localize(forI18nLabel("SALARY"),salaryFilter)
   #salaryFilter = {op:"lt",value:10000}
   #Salary is less than 10000 (en)
```

Now the problem is that the the upper bound `U` of my generics is `Serializable` and developer inadvertently invoked `localizeEq`, which accepts atomic values, with a parameter of type `SimpleFilter<?>` that extends `Serializable`. The method `localizeEq` builds a filter text "[field name] is equal to {op:null,value:null}".

The main issue is the null check. Methods that operate on atomic values (e.g. localizeEq, localizeNe) check if the parameter is null. Methods that operate on complex filters check that either the filter parameter is null **or** its value is null before going on.

That is the reason of the question. Obviously I <strike>can</strike> *(will amend my code in order to)* inspect the type of the `value` parameter when the method is invoked but has three drawbacks:

- Developers find it only at runtime
- Developers find the problem only when `value` is not null
- Nobody in my company runs automated tests, so they will find out only when kickstarting the entire application and setting a non-null value to the filter. Once a manual test is done, it is never repeated

[Edit]
For my specific case there is another trick, but it involves creating more than a dozen overloaded deprecated methods:

```
@Deprecated
public static String localize[Eq|Ne...](Localizable fieldName, SimpleFilter<?> value){ throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Wrong method");}
```

[Edit 3]

The code is on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/djechelon/a52ebe31d755f54f368200470e96a127). Please note that in repository code we statically import `SimpleFilter.filter` or `LocalDateRangeFilter.filter` methods. In the question it is assumed that `localize(Localizable,SimpleFilter)` is part of the same class than other methods. And please note there are a few other *RangeFilter classes to support Joda Time, Java Util Date and NumericRange in our repository. They all suffer same issue.

I would like to focus anyway on the scope of the question: forbidding extension in generic, which seems not possible in the JLS.

Comment: The only approach I can think of is to create an interface / abstract class that allowed classes implement /extend (can be totally empty, doesn't matter) and have your type parameter use that. But that comes with its own drawbacks, and doesn't 100% solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was going to do. Simply because I don't only have SimpleFilter but also date-related filter classes. All them would extend `ComplexFilter` to simplify `instanceof`

Comment: If they're all similar in functionality, then an abstract class would be my go-to, I think. I am unaware of Java having anything more advanced for type paramaters than  <? extends Interface/AbstractClass>

Comment: I'm having a great deal of difficulty mapping your words to the pseudocode you've presented.  The only type bound I see is `Number`, not `Object` or `Serializable`, and the signature of that method should not accept an argument of type `SimpleFilter<?>`.

Comment: I did a mistake. I confused SimpleFilter (bound to anything) with NumericRangeFilter (bound to numbers). Rewriting parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to ask if it is possible in Java 8+ to declare a generic
>   bound `T` so that it extends superclass/superinterface `U` (which could be
>   `Object`, or `Serializable`) but breaks compilation if `T` extends `L` (which
>   must extend `U` first).

The `T` in your pseudocode seems to be a type parameter, not a bound.  Bounds are something different, and in fact, putting a bound on `T` seems to be what you are asking about.  Indeed, without one -- in particular, without a *lower* bound -- your `localizeEq()` method is not gaining anything from being generic.  As it stands, that method would be clearer if you just got rid of `T` altogether, and declared the second parameter to be of type `Object` (which would be equivalent to the current code) or `Serializable` or whatever.

I take it that the method was made generic in hopes of somehow using its type parameter to exclude arguments of certain subtypes, but that is not possible in Java, because

- lower type bounds are *inclusive*, not exclusive
- lower type bounds limit types meeting the bound to a single line of inheritance, which seems inconsistent with your intent

> Now the problem is that the the upper bound U of my generics is
>   `Serializable` and developer inadvertently invoked `localizeEq`, which
>   accepts atomic values, with a parameter of type `SimpleFilter<?>` that
>   extends `Serializable`. The method `localizeEq` builds a filter text
>   "[field name] is equal to {op:null,value:null}".

If one is not supposed to pass a `SimpleFilter` to the `localizedEq()` method then I'd say that you have a design flaw here.  You could catch violations at *run*time, of course, but the type system does not provide a way to express the compile-time constraint you're looking for.

> For my specific case there is another trick, but it involves creating more than a dozen overloaded deprecated methods:

Indeed, overloading is probably the best available solution, but I would suggest approaching it from the other direction.  Instead of adding overloads for `localizeEq`, `localizeNe`, *etc.*, **deprecate** the existing versions of those methods and instead overload `localize` with a version or versions that provide the wanted behavior for arguments that are not `SimpleFilter`s.